# Disabling TLS v1.1 Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, glassfish

Is there any way to disable the use of TLS v1.1 (and v1) for all SSL configured listeners in Glassfish 4.1? I've tried to set the JVM property

```
-Ddeployment.security.TLSvX.Y=false
```

as recommended by this Oracle blog post (https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls) but the protocols are still being used in the https negotiations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i've found how to do it by messing around with Glassfish command interface. 
Run the following commands:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.tls-enabled=false

asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.tls11-enabled=false
```

And this will leave only **TLSv1.2** enabled. This commands are run against the default HTTPS listener (port 8181), so remember to run against any other secure HTTP listener if you need to.

Comment: If you have the admin panel on other port, you just need to specify the port, so just add --port xxxx at the end of the commands... great help!